# Creating a non-root portable install of MySQL server for Linux?

Tags: linux, mysql

Is there a non-root, portable distribution of MySQL for Linux?

I need to do some testing on a server that I do not have root access to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are building from the tarbal, you would typically do something like

```
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME
```

which after `make` has finished and you do `make install` will put all the bit in subdirectories of *your home directory*.

Then you may need to add `$HOME/bin` to your `PATH` environment variable and `$HOME/lib` to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and make a few other adjustments like that.

Comment: That's for the install, but what about opening a service on a privileged port as non-root?

Comment: By default, 3306 is not a privileged port as it is upper than 1023. So no need to be root.

Comment: *"what about opening a service on a privileged port as non-root?"* Use a non-privileged port. As Dom says 3306 (the MySQL default) is fair game, and it is typical to substitute 8080 or 8888 for 80 when doing userspace httpd.

Answer (score 1):

[XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html) is a portable (W|L)AMP web server that can be put on a USB stick if you like.